# JavaFX TableView with Table form List

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I have a program to connect with Database, list Tables, and print Table, and here is my problem:

I have a TableView controller and ListView controller. After connection, User have to choose a Table, then I get ListView value and then I want to set TableView to print correct Table. I was looking in google to find any solution but I can't find my case. Is it possible to set this View dynamically?

This is my program:
[image]

```
            Statement myState = conn.createStatement();

            DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
            String[] types = {"TABLE"};

            ListView<String> myTables = new ListView<String>();
            rs = md.getTables(conn.getCatalog(), conn.getSchema(), "%", types);
            List<String> arrayListTables = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                arrayListTables.add(rs.getString(3));
            }
            tableList.getItems().addAll(arrayListTables);
            tableList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Just get the selected item from the selection model of the `ListView`. Depending on the interaction that should result in the `TableView` being filled you may need to add a listener to the `selectedItem` property...

Comment: Any example of code, I wanna add I had problem with ObservableList in my ListView I have strings, and the tableView want to method .setItems ObserableList object

Comment: Not really possible to create a suitable example given the info in the question. A better description of the user interaction that results in the `TableView` being filled and some code that demonstrates how you'd retrieve the data would benefit the question. Please [edit] the question to include this info.

Comment: Use reflection api or use hashmap